Why is ACAT not identifying the difference between 2 bridge sites on a surface slab?
I am using ACAT (Alloy Catalysis Automated Toolkit) to determine the unique adsorption sites on a 4x4x4 slab of Re3Pd. I've used the following code to identify these unique sites:
surface_atoms = read('{0}/{1}_POSCAR'.format(surface_directory, surface_name))
sas = SlabAdsorptionSites(surface_atoms, surface=surface_symmetry, label_sites=True, composition_effect=True, optimize_surrogate_cell=True)
unique_sites = sas.get_unique_sites(unique_composition=True, unique_subsurf=True)

For this surface, I would expect 3 unique bridge sites, and indeed I did get different adsorption energies between the 3 using VASP:

The 3 bridge sites would be:

The bridge between Re-Pd, Ex: atoms 30 and 57
The long bridge between Re-Re, Ex: atoms 25 and 27
The short bridge between Re-Re, Ex: atoms 27 and 58

Upon running this code, however, only 2 bridge sites are identified, and it seems to think the long and short bridge sites are the same. Is there anything I'm doing wrong that would lead to this? I tried changing the tol parameter to 0.1 instead of the default 0.5, thinking it might be registering the 2 as symmetric because they have too similar distances, but this actually output LESS unique sites (8 total unique sites before, 5 unique after. I expect 9 unique sites)

Shameless plug for SurfGraph code that I wrote.  I think it would catch this for you.  Not converting to an answer because it feels too self serving and I do not have the time to make an example for you right now.  Feel free to let me know if you have any issues though. https://surfgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Usage.html#generate-sites-py

Actually maybe I do not understand the problem.  Can you label the sites in your question?  Is the surface not 111

After reading through the code for get_unique_sites, I don't see any considerations for symmetry. It seems that the criterion for a unique site is a unique value for a tuple of given properties:
for i, s in enumerate(sl):
                sig = tuple(s[k] for k in key_list)
                if sig not in seen_tuple:
                    seen_tuple.append(sig)
                    if return_site_indices:
                        s = i
                    unq_sites.append(s)

The only properties that would be included for consideration when running my code would be the site type (bridge), the morphology (same because flat surface), and the atom types (same between Re-Re sites). In this case it doesn't seem that this function will do what I need it to do. I am going to try SpacegroupAnalyzer from pymatgen to compare the sites by spatial symmetry as I desire.
Edit: using SpacegroupAnalyzer.get_space_group_operations() and the function SpacegroupOperations.are_symmetrically_equivalent() I was able to get the desired functionality.
    surface_atoms = read('{0}/{1}_POSCAR'.format(surface_directory, surface_name))
    sas = SlabAdsorptionSites(surface_atoms, surface=surface_symmetry, label_sites=True, composition_effect=True, optimize_surrogate_cell=True)

    structure = Structure.from_file('{0}/{1}_POSCAR'.format(surface_directory, surface_name))
    sg = SpacegroupAnalyzer(structure)
    sgo = sg.get_space_group_operations()
    sites = sas.get_sites()

    def s_i(ite):
        return [structure[i] for i in ite['indices']]
    def same_site(site1, site2):
        same_type = len(site1['indices']) == len(site2['indices']) and site1['site'] == site2['site']
        return same_type and sgo.are_symmetrically_equivalent(s_i(site1), s_i(site2))
    unique_sites = []
    for site in sites:
        if not any([same_site(site, isite) for isite in unique_sites]):
            unique_sites.append(site)

